# My picture is not outputting to the frame

Tags: java, jframe

```
    //Draw Bart
    ImageIcon imgBart = new ImageIcon("bart.png");
    g2.drawImage(imgBart.getImage(), 1, 50, this);
```

I tried multiple variations of code but the image is still not outputting towards the frame. I have all png file in the correct place already but it does not output.

Comment: `ImageIcon` is renowned for failing silently when it can't load the image.  I would recommend using [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) instead, this will throw an exception if the image failed to load - this is a good starting point.  Continued failure without exception would require a [mcve]

Comment: *I have all png file in the correct place* - how do you know? What is the "correct place"? If the image was in the correct place then your code should work. Search the site. This question is asked over and over.